# whoever he has bribed / no matter who he has bribed

Tags: meaning

a. Whoever he has bribed, he won't get what he is after.

b. No matter who he has bribed, he won't get what he is after.

Are the meanings different in any way?

Consider two situations:

1. The person he has bribed has not done what he needs done and therefore he will not get what he is after.
2. The person he has bribed will not di what he needs done and therefore he will not get what he is after.

Which of the sentences (a) and (b) be preferrable in each of the cases (1) and (2)?

I think both will work in both cases. I think the only difference is that (b) is more emphatic.

Many thanks

Comment: Nobody ever says 'whomever'. Just nobody.

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael.  I have edited my question. I wrote 'whoever' instead of 'whomever'.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence (a), "Whoever he has bribed, he won't get what he is after," is a general statement with less focus on the act of bribing. Sentence (b), on the other hand, places more emphasis on the actd, reinforcing that regardless of who is bribed, the desired result will not be achieved; it is more emphatic and definitive.

Regarding the two scenarios you propose, the first situation, where the person bribed has not undertook the required action, sees both sentences fitting, but sentence (b) might be slightly more apt due to its stronger emphasis on the ineffectiveness of any bribery. In the second scenario, where the bribed individual will not undertake the necessary action, both sentences are suitable again, yet sentence (b) more forcefully conveys the certainty that the act of bribery, irrespective of the recipient, will not lead to the sought-after result.

TL;DR: Both sentences (a) and (b) are suitable for the given scenarios, but sentence (b) is more emphatic about the ineffectiveness of bribery.

Hope this helps ;)